# Catching errorException when its thrown in Laravel and Livewire

Tags: php, laravel

So I want to catch an exception which is made in a function of the Parser of an API I am using:

```
public static function throwHabboAPIException($data)
{
    // Do we find 'maintenance' anywhere?
    if (strstr($data, 'maintenance')) {
        throw new MaintenanceException("Hotel API is down for maintenance");
    }

    // Check if data is JSON
    if ($data[0] == "{") { // Quick 'hack' to see if this could be JSON
        $json = json_decode($data, true);
        if (isset($json['errors'])) {
            if ($json['errors'][0]['msg'] == "user.invalid_name") {
                throw new UserInvalidException("The name you supplied appears to be invalid");
            }
            $defaultMessage = $json['errors'][0]['msg'];
        } else if (isset($json['error'])) {
            if (preg_match('#not-found#', $json['error'])) {
                throw new \Exception("We can not find the Habbosssss you're looking for");
            }

        } else {
            $defaultMessage = $json;
        }
    } else {
        $defaultMessage = "An unknown HTML page was returned";
    }

    throw new Exception("Unknown HabboAPI exception occurred: " . $defaultMessage);
}
```

I tried making code to intercept the exception  but the above exception is thrown but not catch in livewire

```
                     public function render()
{
    try{
    $items = training_type::all();
    return view('livewire.trainings', compact('items'));
    }
    catch(\Exception $exception){
        return back()->withError($exception->getMessage())->withInput();

    }
}
```

Here is the Exception Class:

```
    namespace HabboAPI\Exceptions;

use Exception;

class HabboNotFoundException extends Exception
{
    public function __construct($message, $code = 0, Exception $previous = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return __CLASS__ . ": [{$this->code}]: {$this->message}\n";
    }
}
```